# How to create Azure Batch service Application pool with custom image in .Net SDK or PowerShell or ARM Template

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-batch

I am referring this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-create-portal

And I have my custom VHD file with me and i want to create application pool with custom VHD file (Nodes) through .Net SDK or PowerShell or ARM Template. I am able to create it from Azure portal

any examples ?

Comment: You can follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images  ...then use this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-create-cli then look for `az batch pool create` you can set the `--image` parameter with your custom image which is now in the form of `/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myImage`

Comment: I am trying the same through powershell it says New-AzureBatchPool : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Comment: Below is my code
$imageReference = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSImageReference" -ArgumentList @("/subscriptions/############/resourceGroups/RG-OneGolden/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/OMGoldenImage")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can prepare a managed image from a VHD, from an Azure VM with
>   managed disks, or from a VM snapshot. For Batch, we recommend creating
>   a managed image from a VM with managed disks or a VM snapshot.

With the test, it seems you just can make your custom VHD file into a managed image to create the batch backend pool as above. Also from the description of the parameter `--image` for the command [`az batch pool create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/pool?view=azure-cli-latest#optional-parameters).

Comment: I am trying the same through powershell it says New-AzureBatchPool : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'